# Cumulatively add number between rows in order to create new columns BUT with diffent way for the first element occurent in a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

this post is related to this one: [Cumulatively add number between rows in order to create new columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318736/cumulatively-add-number-between-rows-in-order-to-create-new-columns-in-r/73319956#73319956r/73319956#73319956)

But with other rules.

I have a dataframe such as

```
Sp1 start end  
A   100   1077 
B   2316  4088
B   26647 28746
B   50000 60000
C   450    789
```

and I would like to add two new columns where I cumulatively add previous `start` and `end` coordinates

But I do not treat the same way when the first Sp1 appear compared to the other ones in the dataframe.

for first I should always get the same columns for the first row:

```
Sp1 start end     new_start  new_end 
A   100   1077    100        1077
```

Then for the **first** B :

```
Sp1 start end     new_start  new_end 
A   100   1077    100        1077
B   2316  4088    1078       2850
```

- `where 1078 = 1077 +1`
- `where 2850 = 1078+(4088-2316)`

for the **other B** it is different since it not the first B, so I do differently:

```
Sp1 start end     new_start  new_end 
A   100   1077    100        1077
B   2316  4088    1078       2850
B   26647 28746   25409      27508
```

- where `2850 + (26647-4088) =  25409`
- where `25409+ (28746-26647) = 27508`

For the Third B it is the same as the second B:

```
Sp1 start end     new_start  new_end 
A   100   1077    100        1077
B   2316  4088    1078       2850
B   26647 28746   25409      27508
B   50000 60000   48762      58762
```

- where `27508 + (50000-28746) =  48762`
- where `48762+ (60000-50000) = 58762`

for the C it is the **first C**, so I do as :

```
Sp1 start end     new_start  new_end 
A   100   1077    100        1077
B   2316  4088    1078       2850
B   26647 28746   25409      27508
B   50000 60000   48762      58762
C   450   789     58763      59101
```

- where `58763 = 58762 +1`
- where `59101 = 58762 +(789-450)`

Then at the end, I should get the expect result:

Sp1 start end     new_start  new_end
A   100   1077    100        1077
B   2316  4088    1078       2850
B   26647 28746   25409      27508
B   50000 60000   48762      58762
C   450   789     58763      59101

If someone has an idea, it would be amazing !

Here is the dataframe in dput format if it can help :

```
structure(list(Sp1 = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), start = c(100L, 
2316L, 26647L, 50000L, 450L), end = c(1077, 4088, 28746, 60000, 
789)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't compute all columns at once (you need to wait for previous iterations to be able to compute the result for line `i`), just use a loop. The row number per `Sp1` can be done at once using `dplyr`:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Sp1) %>% mutate(sp_row = row_number()) %>% ungroup()
df$new_start <- df$new_end <- NA
df$new_start[1] <- df$start[1]
df$new_end[1] <- df$end[1]
for( i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$sp_row[i]==1) {
    df$new_start[i] <- df$new_end[i-1]+1
    df$new_end[i] <- df$new_start[i]+df$end[i]-df$start[i]
  }
  if(df$sp_row[i]!=1) {
    df$new_start[i] <- df$start[i]-df$new_end[i-1]
    df$new_end[i] <- df$new_start[i]+df$end[i]-df$start[i]
  }
}
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Sp1   start   end new_start new_end sp_row
  <chr> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
1 A       100  1077       100    1077      1
2 B      2316  4088      1078    2850      1
3 B     26647 28746     23797   25896      2
4 B     50000 60000     24104   34104      3
5 C       450   789     34105   34444      1
```

There is at least one mistake in your example btw: `50000-25896 =  29053` is wrong.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I edited my post at the end to show you the issue I'm facing with my data and your code

Comment: Wow sorry, I just saw my mistake, I just edited the expected calculations when the sp_row !=1, sorry for that. Now it should be more easy to undestrand

Comment: So I replace the following in your code and it works now thank you !!! : ```df$new_start[i] <- df$new_end[i-1] + (df$start[i]-df$end[i-1])
    df$new_end[i] <- df$new_start[i]+ (df$end[i]-df$start[i])```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `tidyverse` based on `accumulate` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66796202/3460670). This does require a couple of extra columns, including one for `lag` of `end`, and a second to indicate first row for a group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(lag_end = lag(end)) %>%
  group_by(Sp1) %>%
  mutate(Sp1_first = row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  nest_by(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(result = accumulate(
    data[-1],
    .init = tibble(new_start = df$start[1], new_end = df$end[1]),
    ~ tibble(
      new_start = ifelse(.y$Sp1_first, .x$new_end + 1, .x$new_end + (.y$start - .y$lag_end)),
      new_end = new_start + (.y$end - .y$start)
    ))) %>%
  unnest_wider(data) %>%
  unnest_wider(result) %>%
  select(-lag_end, -Sp1_first)
```

**Output**

```
     id Sp1   start   end new_start new_end
  <int> <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 A       100  1077       100    1077
2     2 B      2316  4088      1078    2850
3     3 B     26647 28746     25409   27508
4     4 B     50000 60000     48762   58762
5     5 C       450   789     58763   59102
```